# Wordpress permalinks and javascript redirection

Tags: permalinks, javascript, redirect

I need to use javascript redirection in one of my scripts. With `/%postname%/` WP permalinks structure redirection works like it should but with default it always redirects to home page.

`/%postname%/` structure script:

```
window.location.replace(encodeURIComponent("http://www.url.com/customposttype/postslug"));
```

default permalinks structure script:

```
window.location.replace(encodeURIComponent("http://www.url.com/?customposttype=postslug"))
```

Comment: Does the page load properly when you put `http://www.url.com/?customposttype=postslug` into your browser?

Comment: Yes it loads normaly

Comment: But when the script runs on the page, you are saying to loads the home page? Does the actual correct URL show up in the browser url bar, or does it just load the home page directly?

Comment: Correct URL shows but it loads home page

Comment: Check the browser title bar - are you sure it's not loading a 404 / Page not found?

Comment: It shows homepage title. When I hit enter in URL bar it goes to right page

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your script is doing a replace, but really what you want is to *set* the window location:

Change your redirects from:

```
window.location.replace(encodeURIComponent("http://www.url.com/?customposttype=postslug"))
```

to

```
window.location = "http://www.url.com/?customposttype=postslug";
```

And it should work properly.

Comment: Same thing. I noticed that if i put anything instead of that custom post type same thing happens. Like in the moment of redirection custom post type is not defined yet